# Navigation Bar is setting tint color when user drag

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I'm working on a app where I have a main view controller with a table view on it. And when the user touches an item of the table view, the app segue to a detail view controller.
The detail view controller has got a clear color navigation bar while the main view controller has got a white color navigation bar.
My issue is that when I'm at the detail view controller and I drag the left border of the view and try to swipe left to go back to the main view controller, the navigation bar turns to white color. And if I don't complete the move and stays on the detail view controller, the navigation bar keeps white.
This gif shows the situation better:

[image]

So, How can I avoid the navigation bar on turning white color when I try to drag the view?

UPDATE:
On the main view controller:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

On the detail view controller:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
    self.navigationController.toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
}
```

Comment: Could you show us some code ? How and when do you set the color of your navigation bars ?

Comment: @Randy I just edited the question with some code.

Comment: Could you try to move what you are doing in `viewDidLoad` and in `viewWillAppear` to `viewDidAppear` ? ( in your detail view controller )

Comment: You're welcome, I added an answer, you can accept it so everybody can see quickly see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move what you put in viewDidLoad and in viewWillAppear to viewDidAppear ( in your detail view controller )

Answer (score 0):

In detail view controller: add below code in ViewWillApper methode.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                                              forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 60)];
bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[self.view addSubview:bg];
```